# How to get rid of /etc/gitconfig in git?

Tags: git, git-config

I have two `gitconfig` files:

- `/etc/gitconfig`
- `~/.gitconfig`

I want to get rid of `/etc/gitconfig`. I can't just remove it, because I have no write permission in that directory.

Is there another way to disable the `gitconfig` file in `/etc/gitconfig`?

Comment: It seems odd that you are working locally with a repo folder, but you can't edit some of the files.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is that strange to you ? I'm working on a server, but the admin guy has the /etc/gitconfig messed up. So I have to disable it.

Comment: Wait...are you saying that the _global_ `.gitconfig` is not accessible _and_ messed up, and then you want to disable it?

Comment: It just makes me wonder *why* the admin person has messed up the system gitconfig file, *how* it is messed up in such a way that the user gitconfig can't override that behaviour, and why the admin person can't repair the messed-up system gitconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

The manual page for `git-config` (`git config --help`) states:

> ENVIRONMENT
>
> GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM
>
> Whether to skip reading settings from the system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig file. See git(1) for details.